# Google IOT device telemetry to stackdriver

Tags: mqtt, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-iot

I'd like to use Google IOT to periodically send out custom telemetry which I'd like to ingest into Stackdriver for alerting purposes. Is this doable? As far as I can tell, I cannot seem to load up custom events or telemetry in Stackdriver.

A naive example of this would be, assume an IOT device such as a thermostat and assume the thermostat also has access to its in-memory usage data. I know I can periodically push this data up to Google IOT, but I'd like to chart it in Stackdriver and alert on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you start using IoT Core, the MQTT broker in that product brings the telemetry data over into Pub/Sub, and those messages should be showing up in Stackdriver. It'll just "work" by virtue of using Cloud IoT Core.

Is there a reason you'd want to use Stackdriver specifically though? Might be easier just to like, write a quickie Cloud Function that listens to the Pub/Sub topic and does what you need to do from there?

Comment: Agreed, thats what I ended up doing and its a far better solution